# Program behaves differently at different optimisation levels

Tags: c, embedded, avr, avr-gcc

I have written a simple program to familiarise myself with a new MCU.  However, my program does not run correctly at optimisation level -O3.

I am using Microchip Studio (Version 7.0.2594) (formerly Atmel Studio); compiling with avr-gcc 5.4.0; and the microcontroller is an ATmega32M1.

At all compilation levels except -O3, LEDs attached to output PB5 and PD6 both blink with a period of 8 seconds.  This is the intended behaviour.   However, at optimisation level -O3, only the LED attached to output PB5 blinks, while output PD6 remains low.

**Is this an obvious error on my behalf, or is it some kind of compiler bug?**
And, in the unlikely event it *is* a compiler bug, how can I deal with it?

My code is reproduced below:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

static uint64_t execution_time;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Setup functions

static inline void SetClock(void) {
    //Set clock to external crystal highest speed (8MHz):  
    //(These instructions must be completed in 4 clock cycles or less)
    CLKPR = 0x80;   //set CLKPCE, clear all else.
    CLKPR = 0x00;   //Clear CLKPCE, set CLKPS[3:0] to 0. (Smallest prescale - fastest speed.)
}

static inline void SetTimer1(void) {
    //set up timer/counter 1 (CTC mode, TOP = OCR1A)
    TCCR1A = 0;             //WGM0 & WGM1 = 0
    TCCR1B = 0x0D;          //set WGM[3:0] = 0,1,0,0 (CTC with OCR1A as TOP); CS1[2:0] = 1,0,1 (internal timer, prescale 1024)
    OCR1A = 0x7A12;         //TOP = 31250; 4000.0 ms - This means an accurate count can be kept as well as the faster count.
    TIMSK1 = 1<<OCIE1A;     //Interrupt on Timer 1 reaching OCR1A.
    //The Timer will run at 7.8125 ticks per ms.
}

void InitOutputs(void) {
    DDRB |= 0x7 << DDB5;    //SPARE6, 7, 10
    DDRC |= 0x3 << DDC6;    //SPARE8, 9
    DDRD |= 0x7 << DDD5 | 0x3 << DDD0;  //SPARE11, 12, 13 && RELAY H & L
}

void Setup(void) {
    //Set up the various parts of the hardware.
    SetClock();
    
    SetTimer1();
    
    InitOutputs();

    sei();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Functional... functions

void TestISR(void) {
    static uint64_t last_time;
    if (execution_time > last_time) {
        PIND = 1 << PORTD6;
        last_time = execution_time;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    Setup();
    
    while (1) {
        TestISR();
    }
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
    execution_time += 4000;
    PINB = 1 << PORTB5;
}
```

Comment: If optimization changes the behavior of a program, it usually means the program invokes undefined behavior somewhere. Optimizers assume that no UB will happen, and this allows them to generate different code.

Comment: You have no synchronization on `execution_time` between the ISR and the `main` loop, so the interrupt handler has undefined behavior. The compiler is free to assume that `execution_time` can't ever change in the loop. It needs to be a lock-free atomic instead.

Comment: @user17732522 If I changed ```execution_time``` to ```uint8_t```, that would make it atomic (though it would hinder the usability of the value); but what do you mean by lock-free?

Comment: @Infinite_Maelstrom No, `uint8_t` isn't atomic either. You want one of the atomic types listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) such as `atomic_uchar` or some platform-specific atomics implementation if the standard ones aren't supported. Regarding lock-freeness you must make sure that the atomic can't deadlock because it is implemented with locks. So you need to make sure that the atomic is lock-free by looking at the macros provided for them (see same page).

Comment: @user17732522 OK... This looks like an entire area of programming I was completely unaware of - I previously assumed an atomic operation was just one where the operand's size matched the architecture.  I'll have to investigate further.  Thanks.

Comment: @Infinite_Maelstrom You don't need most of it. Most of it is specific to multithreading, not interrupts/signals on the same thread. It is also possible to achieve the same effect for interrupt handlers with careful use of `volatile` or other optimization barriers coupled with knowledge of the architecture and compiler behavior, but that's not standardized.

Comment: @user17732522 you are abstracting from the reference frame. The question is about atmega

Comment: I don't have any real experience with AVR, but from what I can tell the only fully correct approach in general is to disable interrupts as suggested by the already posted answer. The instruction set doesn't seem to generally support proper atomics for any type.

Comment: Did you look into the generated assembly of the differently optimized executables? This will give you a good start point to explain _what_ is actually happening. The _why_ is another issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable needs to be `volatile`

```
static volatile uint64_t execution_time;
```

otherwise when you enable optimizations reads from it will be optimized out as the compiler does not see any program path which may modify this variable (ISRs are not called from your code)

On the other hand as your operations are not atomic they are not thread-safe. On tiny uC like atmega I suggest disabling interrupts when you access this variable in the main program.)

```
void TestISR(void) {
    static uint64_t last_time;
    uint64_t execution_time_copy;
    cli();
    execution_time_copy = execution_time;
    sei();
    if (execution_time_copy > last_time) {
        PIND = 1 << PORTD6;
        last_time = execution_time_copy;
    }
}
```

> or is it some kind of compiler bug

The compiler would be rather useless if it would fail compiling such a trivial program. Assume: it is always your program

Comment: Is it guaranteed on ATmega32M1 with GCC that reading/writing a `uint64_t` will not tear so that an interrupt can arrive half way? If not, then I don't think `volatile` will be enough.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes - it is a very simple uC.  When interrupts are disabled nothing will interrupt the reading or writing

Comment: I am talking about the `volatile` suggestion which presumably is a separate alternative from disabling interrupts.

Comment: @user17732522 It is enough

Comment: Rather than disable, access data and enable, better to save enable state, disable, access data and then restore state.

Comment: Please note that it is very bad practice to toggle the global interrupt mask from inside drivers. Instead enable/disable the _specific_ interrupt you are dealing with. Otherwise the code is very disruptive to other interrupts present in the final program and you create "tight coupling" between all manner of unrelated code.

Comment: @0___________ Isn't reading/writing a `uint64_t` on an ATmega32M1 multiple instructions, and couldn't an interrupt happen between them?

Comment: It may, bit it will wait untill you enable the interrupts again

Comment: Just to make sure that there is no confusion here. Both is required, using `volatile` to prevent optimization and disabling interrupts to guarantee atomic access to the uint64_t.